# jQuery full text table search

Tags: jquery, full-text-search

I need to implement some full text searching on table. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLae3y46/1/) is a snippet I have found, but it only searches through the first column of a table, i.e. ID column. I need to improve this to search through whole table. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);
            var id = $row.find("td").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else { 
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried playing with `var id = $row.find("td").text();` but to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Dont re-invent the wheel, use  [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: If you want use the script you found u just have to modify it ab bit:https://jsfiddle.net/878d1n41/

Comment: DataTables looks promising - will definitely try :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use u just have to change the condition ab bit:

FROM:

```
if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
```

TO:

```
if (id.indexOf(value) === -1) {
```

COMPLETE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);
            var id = $row.find("td").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) === -1) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else { 
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy...looks like I have yet a lot to learn :) Thank you very much :)